# Keycloak integration with vertx

Tags: java, vert.x, keycloak, keycloak-services

I have a requirement to authenticate the users against keycloak when vertx API is called. As I am new to keycloak. Can anyone suggest how I can achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I followed this tutorial to set up keycloak.  There are a couple issues with the current version of vertx web 3.5.1 but I was able to get it to work on vertx web 3.4.2.  https://vertx.io/blog/vertx-3-and-keycloak-tutorial/